# Why is the unknotting number of Borromean rings 1?

Tags: knot-theory

Wikipedia claims that the unknotting number of the [Borromean rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borromean_rings) is 1, which I believe means that they can be totally separated if we are allowed to pass the rings through themselves in a single place. However it seems that making a single crossing switch in the Borromean rings would always leave two of the rings more linked than they were to start with? What have I misunderstood?

Comment: I think we're allowed to pass the rings through themselves again, in the same place, the same as if we had cut one of them.

Comment: Linkinfo says the unlinking number is two. I don't have a proof immediately though I'd wager heavily that wikipedia is mistaken. http://www.indiana.edu/~linkinfo/results.php?searchmode=0&category%5B%5D=%3C%3D6&category%5B%5D=%3D7&category%5B%5D=%3D8&category%5B%5D=%3D9&name=%3D1&unlinking_number=%3D1&startrow=1&rows=20

Comment: It seems they confused it with the minimum number of components to remove to disconnect the rest.

Comment: I don't see the wikipedia page saying that anywhere.  Where did you see this?

Comment: @N.Owad it's in the infobox at the top right of the page. (I think just top of the page if you're on mobile)

Comment: Ah, okay.  Yes, I think you are right, but after a quick search I could not find any information about the unknotting number of the Borromean rings from different sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, the unknotting (unlinking, really) number is 2.

To see that it is at most 2, simply notice that changing the two crossings shared by a pair of components will unlink the link.

To see that it is at least 2, we follow [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01386.pdf) which provides an overview of several ways of bounding the unlinking number from below. In particular, if we take the chessboard shading in which the unbounded region is unshaded and choose a labeling of the four shaded regions, then following the notation of the paper, $\iota(c) = -1$ for every crossing, and so the Goeritz matrix becomes

$$G = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -3 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix has full rank so by Proposition 4, page 6, the unlinking number $u(L)$ satisfies

$$u(L) \geq 3 - 1 - 0 = 2.$$

Comment: It is rather easy to give an example of a Brunnian link with three components unlinking number one. Take the Hopf link and Bing double one of the components and Whitehead double the other component.

Comment: The question only concerns the Borromean rings.

Comment: To show that the unlinking number is not 1, you need to show that for ANY diagram for the link there is no unlinking crossing (not just the one you know). This is why unknotting and unlinking are very subtle questions (and if you look at the linkinfo page there are even 10 crossings links where we don't know the unlinking number). In particular there can be diagrams with self crossings that are unlinking (as in the example I outlined above).  Please make sure to understand the definitions at play before answering.